# Background process in shell script receives EOF

Tags: c, shell, stdin, system-calls, background-process

It's hard to explain this behavior, so here's a reproducible example (tested on macOS).

First, I have the following C file. The details aren't important, but I essentially use the [`read` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to read 16 bytes from standard input, or until an EOF is encountered. Note that `read` will return 0 on an EOF.

```c
// test.c

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buf[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1) == 0) {
            printf("EOF encountered! Number of bytes read: %d\n", i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Read all 16 bytes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I compile this file into a binary file called `test`. Here's the program in action:

```sh
$ echo 'sixteen bytes!!' | ./test
Read all 16 bytes

$ echo '' | ./test
EOF encountered! Number of bytes read: 1

$ ./test # Waits for user input
```

Makes sense right? I can even take the last command and run it as a background process (although this is quite useless):

```sh
$ ./test &
[1] 19204

[1]  + suspended (tty input)  ./test
```

Suppose I take this command and put it in the following shell script (called `huh.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

./test &
```

When I run this shell script, here's the output:

```sh
$ ./huh.sh

EOF encountered! Number of bytes read: 0
```

This means `read` immediately encountered an EOF, and this **only happens** in the context of a shell script.

I see similar behavior if I replace `test` with another program that is sensitive to EOFs. For instance, if I instead run `node &` directly in a terminal, I'll be able to see the `node` process in the output of `ps`. However, if I run `node &` in a shell script, it immediately exits.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job control is enabled by default in interactive shells, but disabled by default in shell scripts. Here's a relevant quote [from POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02):

> If job control is disabled (see set, -m), the standard input for an asynchronous list, before any explicit redirections are performed, shall be considered to be assigned to a file that has the same properties as /dev/null. This shall not happen if job control is enabled.

Comment: Very good — POSIX (your answer) vs Bash (my answer), but they're defining essentially the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, background commands in a shell script are run differently from background commands typed at the terminal.  See the Bash manual on [Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists), where it says:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘`&`’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the *background,* and these are referred to as *asynchronous* commands. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true). When job control is not active (see [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control)), the standard input for asynchronous commands, in the absence of any explicit redirections, is redirected from `/dev/null`.

Job control is not normally active in a script.

Note that this behaviour in Bash is consistent with the requirements of the [POSIX shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64999652/15168), as noted by [Joseph Sible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica).